# Renaming multiple files in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I need to copy all xlsm files from the May directory into the June directory (that part is easy, I've already done that). My issue is with all the files ending with `"May16.xlsm"`. I want the "May" part of the filename removed and replaced with "Jun".

I can take off the last 5 characters... but I can't figure out how to add them.

I've got 350+ files to rename... and I'd rather not do it manually!

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: @NiclasLarsson batch file is on Windows

Comment: If you want to go the gui route you can use something like [Bulk Rename Utility](http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files).

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, since the OP tagged his question [tag:ms-dos], NiclasLarsson's question makes sense...

Comment: @aschipfl yes I saw that before commenting here. Probably a mistake because in DOS you don't even have 4-character extension, and DOS has almost gone extinct for more than a decade

Comment: I'm on wyse terminal that runs windows 7 via a windows server, lol.  As for the ms-dos tag -- it came up as a suggestion but I didn't realise I'd selected it!

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, you're right, and the OP already stated he's using Windows; many (new) users don't ever read the tag descriptions; perhaps Niclas wanted to point him to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as complex as you thought

```
ren May* Jun*
```

Will work. Or if you want only `*.xlsm` files

```
ren May*.xlsm Jun*.xlsm
```